# $q$-(and other)-analogs for counting index-$n$ subgroups in terms of Homs to $S_n$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, gr.group-theory, rt.representation-theory, finite-groups, qa.quantum-algebra

The following formula of astonishing beauty and power (imho):

$$ \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{| \mathrm{Hom}(G,S_n) | }{n! } z^n = \exp\left( \sum_{n \ge 1} \frac{|\text{Index}~n~\text{subgroups of}~ G|}nz^n \right)  $$

can be found in e.g. [Qiaochu Yuan blog](https://qchu.wordpress.com/2015/11/15/finite-index-subgroups-of-the-modular-group/)  , here $G$ is a finitely generated group,
$| \mathrm{Hom}(G,S_n) | $ is the number of homomorphisms from $G$ to the symmetric group $S_n$ (pay attention that we count homomorphisms themselves - not up to conjugation). $|\mathrm{Index}~n~\text{subgroups of}~ G|$ is the number of index $n$ subgroups in $G$. (See examples  below). It seems to me that [Tao's post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2017/04/13/counting-objects-up-to-isomorphism-groupoid-cardinality/) is related.

Keeping in mind the heuristics $S_n$ = $\mathrm{GL}$ ([field with one element](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Field_with_one_element)),
it seems natural to think in the following direction:

**Question 1a** Is there $q$-analog of this formula of the following spirit:
let us substitute $S_n$ in the left hand side by $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbf{F}_q)$.
So we are interested in: 
$$ \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{| \mathrm{Hom}(G,\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbf{F}_q)) | }{ [n]_q! } z^n = ??? $$

or in the closely related:

$$ \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{| \mathrm{Hom}(G,\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbf{F}_q)) | }{ |\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbf{F}_q)| } z^n = ??? $$

where $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbf{F}_q)$ is the general linear group over the finite field $\mathbf{F}_q$,
the number of elements in it - almost $q$-factorial: 
$ |\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbf{F}_q)| = [n]_q!
(q-1)^n q^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}$.

**Question 1b** At least if $G$ is a finite group, can one say something about the series appearing in the left-hand side? In the original formula we get $\exp(\text{Polynomial})$; what is an appropriate $q$-analog of it?

*Example 1* Consider $G$ to be trivial group $G= \{\mathrm{Id}\}$ (just identity). 
The original formula reads:

$$ \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{1}{n! } z^n = \exp( z) $$

The $q$-analog-1 reads:

$$ \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{1}{[n]_q ! } z^n = e_q( z) $$

Ура! We got a bit of luck: [$q$-exponential](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Q-exponential) appeared in the right-hand side in complete analogy with original formula. Consideration of $q$-analog-2 also gives something closely related to the $q$-exponential expression.

*Example 2* Consider $G$ to be  $\mathbf{Z}$ (integers - free abelian group with one generator). The original formula reads:

$$ \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{n!}{n! } z^n = exp\left(  \sum_{n \ge 1}  \frac{z^n}n \right) $$

which is indeed true , since $1/(1-z)= \exp(-\log(1-z))$.

The $q$-analog-1 reads:

$$ \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{[n]_q ! (q-1)^n q^{\frac{n(n-1)}{2}}  }{[n]_q ! } z^n = ??? $$

It is not clear what should we get at the right-hand side, but at least the left-hand side looks not terrible: $[n]_q!$ cancels and we get expression similar to [theta function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Theta_function). If we consider $q$-analog-2 we just get $1/(1-z)$ built-in.

*Example 3* Consider $G$ to be  $\mathbf{Z}\oplus \mathbf{Z}$ (pairs of integers - free abelian group with two generators). The left-hand side will involve the number of pairs of commuting elements in $S_n$ - which is equal to number of conjugacy classes in $S_n$ multiplied by the size of $S_n$, so original formula reads:

$$\mathrm{LHS} =  \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{p(n) n!}{n! } z^n = \sum_{n \ge 0} p(n)  z^n$$

In the $q$-case, we again see that $[n]_q !$ cancels and we will get the generating 
function for number of conjugacy classes in $\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbf{F}_q)$, which has a nice expression but is difficult to to recognize as $q$-exponential of what it should be.

*Example ...*  Taking $G=\mathbf{Z}^k$, we will get generating function for number of commuting $k$-tuples in $S_n$ in the original formula; what should be the $q$-analog? Taking $G = \mathbf{Z}/2\mathbf{Z}$ we will get number of involutions; taking $G=\mathbf{Z}/n\mathbf{Z}$, the number of elements of order $n$.

**Question 2** what are the analogs of the original formula if we substitute $S_n$ by the other Weyl groups? And $q$-analogs are other simple algebraic groups over $\mathbf{F}_q$?

**Question 3** For compact Lie groups the left-hand side also has an analog - take $\mathrm{U}(n)$ instead of $S_n$ - consider volumes of $\mathrm{U}(n)/G$...
Is there nice right-hand side?

PS: What is the history of the formula: author? references? Lubotzky seems to attribute it to Müller around the nineties...

Is there some intuitive explanation of the formula? 
How subgroups can be be related to homomorphisms to $S_n$?

Comment: One way I think about that formula is that $G$ acts transitively on the $n$ cosets of a subgroup of index $n$, and permutation representations can be built from transitive permutation representations.

Comment: "$q$-analogues of $S_n$" makes me think "Hecke algebra," though I'm not sure that makes that much sense here...

Comment: @TimothyChow Well ... Hecke algebra is part of GL(n,F_q) - I mean consider group algebra and its part bi-invariant (left and right) for Borel subalgebra  - that will be precisely Hecke algebra. (By Brua decopmposition GL = Borel*S_n*Borel -- so facrotring out Borel - the size will be like S_n, but the product will be deformed). In that way Hecke algebra appeared much earlier than "quantum groups". And its miracle that the same algebra  appeared in Schur-Weyl duality for U_q(gl). On the other hand recent papers relate U_q(gl) and GL(n,F_q)  see:

Comment: Quantum linear groups  an representations of GLn(Fq) J Brundan, R Dipper, AS Kleshchëv - 2001 - books.google.com  https://www.google.ru/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0ahUKEwixp-6z573UAhVGG5oKHZCWCKgQFggpMAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpages.uoregon.edu%2Fbrundan%2Fpapers%2Fgl.pdf&usg=AFQjCNH3n281XlBFzQ0CcshKTBkrKTVLKA&sig2=0xTPAemwCzojDBAlV9uZTA&cad=rjt

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Yes, there's a $q$-analogue. See [this paper of Yoshida from 1992](https://repository.kulib.kyoto-u.ac.jp/dspace/bitstream/2433/82744/1/0794-03.pdf), where $\sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{| \mathrm{Hom}(G,\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbf{F}_q)) | }{ |\mathrm{GL}(n,\mathbf{F}_q)| } z^n$ is expressed in terms of some invariants of the group ring $\mathbb{F}_q G$, at least when $G$ is a finite group (page 27). Yoshida only states the result. A proof appears for instance in [a follow up paper by Chigira, Takegahara and Yoshida](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0021869399983989) from 2000. From their result it follows that when $(|G|,q)=1$, the generating function is a finite product of power series of the form $P(z^a,q^b)$ for various $a$ and $b$, where
$$P(z,q) = \sum_{n \ge 0} \frac{z^n}{|GL(n,\mathbb{F}_{q})|}.$$

The original formula for $S_n$, in terms of generating functions, is due to Wohlfahert, see [this paper from 1977](https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007%2FBF01220437?LI=true). An earlier equivalent result, stated in a different fashion, is due to [Dey (1965)](https://www.cambridge.org/core/services/aop-cambridge-core/content/view/S204061850003522X). Dress and Müller generalized the generating function result to a more general setting [their paper from 1997](http://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0001870897916480), see Proposition 1.

Comment: The attribution to Wohlfahrt is not quite accurate, since an equivalent result (but not in generating function form) was given by I. Dey, *Proc. Glasgow Math. Soc.* **7** (1965), 61-79. For some additional aspects, see Exercise 5.13 of *Enumerative Combinatorics*, vol. 2.

Comment: @RichardStanley Thank you Stanley for you comment. I should have guessed that your book discusses this problem! I added a reference to Dey's paper.

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer ! The papers are very interesting. If you would have comment on further questions: 1) The RHS of q-analog looks different from the orginal formula - how to get q->1 limit ? or we get different fomula  2) The q-analog does not seem to apply to infinite group, in particular Z^n, so not clear how to describe e.g. n-tuples of commuting elements.

Comment: @RichardStanley is q-analog discussed in your book ? (Sorry I do not have EC2). Is the number of commuting m-tuples in GL(n,F_q) known ? (For S_n it follows from the formula, but q-analog mentioned by Ofir does not seems to apply).