# Lie theoretic meaning to $e^{\text{cycle}} = \text{permutation}$?

Tags: co.combinatorics, lie-groups, lie-algebras, generating-functions

It is well known that exponentiating the EGF(exponential generating function) for cycles gives the EGF for permutations: [link here](https://math.berkeley.edu/%7Emhaiman/math172-spring10/exponential.pdf). Usually summarized under the catchy slogan `all = exp(connected)`.

I wonder if it is possible to give a lie-theoretic explanation to this phenomenon: The similarity to `group = exp(algebra)` is tantalizing.

Is there some way to relate the counting done by the EGF function to an *actual* exponential between the 'algebra of cycles' and the group $S_n$? Perhaps there is some way to use the representation theory of $S_n$ to establish some connection? Is this one of those near-misses that holds no deep content?

Comment: Some other questions on somewhat similar "exponential formula": https://mathoverflow.net/questions/272045/q-and-other-analogs-for-counting-index-n-subgroups-in-terms-of-homs-to-s?rq=1

Comment: I think if there is a deep answer to this question, it might involve a combinatorial interpretation of the BCH formula.