# Are degrees of polynomials in Weil's zeta function equal/bounded to/by dimensions of SOME cohomologies in non-smooth or non-projective case?

Tags: ag.algebraic-geometry, rt.representation-theory, finite-fields, weil-conjectures

[Edit] Let me make question more focused. It is about details of [Weil conjectures](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weil_conjectures).

Rationality of zeta function does NOT require the manifold to be smooth & projective, so zeta function is a factor of some polynomials:

$
\frac{P_1(T)\dotsb P_{2n-1}(T)}{P_0(T)\dotsb P_{2n}(T)},
$

**Question** What happens if manifold is not required to be smooth and projective,
is there some cohomology theory which gives / bounds DEGREES of those polynomials
in zeta function ?

Can some version of  [intersection cohomology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intersection_homology) appear in singular case ?
At least for small resolutions ?

If manifold is affine and smooth - is it enough to consider l-adic cohomologies with
compact support ?  (Seems - YES by Ben's answer: [Grothendieck trace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_trace_formula) )

PS:

If manifold is SMOOTH and PROJECTIVE, then as far as I understand degrees of those polynomials equals to dimensions of l-adic cohomologies (which in the case of GOOD REDUCTION coincide with dim $H^i$ over complex numbers (Betti numbers)).

---

**OLD version of question:**

Weil conjectures are "highly influential proposals by André Weil (1949) on the generating functions (known as local zeta-functions) derived from counting the number of points on algebraic varieties over finite fields".
See nice brief surveys on [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Weil_conjectures) or [Tao2014](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2014/05/13/dworks-proof-of-rationality-of-the-zeta-function-over-finite-fields/#more-7479).

Conjectures consist of several statements:

- Rationality of zeta-function
- Functional equation and Poincaré duality for the zeta function
- Riemann hypothesis
- (Betti numbers) If X is a (good) "reduction mod p" of a non-singular projective variety Y defined over a number field embedded in the field of complex numbers, then the degree of Pi is the ith Betti number of the space of complex points of Y.

Item 2 clearly needs that variety to be smooth and projective.
While items 1,3 holds for any quasi-projective (e.g. affine) manifold (see [Tao2014](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2014/05/13/dworks-proof-of-rationality-of-the-zeta-function-over-finite-fields/#more-7479)).

**Question:** What about the last item of the conjectures 
for affine (or quasi-projective) manifolds (not necessarily smooth) -
is there any cohomological interpretation of degrees
of polynomials P_i  (which represent the zeta function)  ?

For example.
Consider the commuting variety: pairs of matrices which commute
or pairs/triples/n-tuples of non-degenerate matrices which commute.
Number of points over finite field is known (at least for pairs)
see e.g. [MO271752](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/271752/number-of-commuting-pairs-triples-n-tuples-in-gl-nf-q-and-other-groups).

**Question 2:** What about particular cases of such manifolds ?

Comment: it is true for all varieties $V$, with no assumption on smoothness or properness. $P_i(T) = {\rm det}(1-FT| H^i_c(V, \mathbb Q_{\ell}))$ is the characteristic polynomial of Frobenius acting on the cohomology with compact support of the variety $V$. Here $\ell$ is any prime different from the characteristic of the finite field. So degree of $P_i$ is always the dimension of $H^i_c(V)$.

Comment: @guest thank you ! What is the reference ?

Answer (score 6):

The number of points always has an interpretation as a supertrace of Frobenius on the compactly supported cohomology, by the [Grothendieck trace formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grothendieck_trace_formula).  The issue is that it can be quite difficult to understand how Frobenius acts in this case.  On a compact smooth variety, it's constrained by Poincare duality (which is basically the Riemann hypothesis); otherwise, it's quite difficult to control, though it can be in special situations.  The most important is that cohomology classes of degree $2d$ that are dual to rational subvarieties still have the expected eigenvalue $p^d$; unfortunately, most varieties will have cohomology classes that don't arise this way.

**EDIT:**  To address the degrees of the polynomials: the degrees of the polynomials are given by the Betti numbers of the etale cohomology of the variety in characteristic $p$.  The roots of the polynomials are the inverses of eigenvalues of Frobenius acting there.  For all but finitely $p$, this will be the same as the cohomology of complex points of the variety, but there's no especially obvious condition for which finitely many p you have to avoid.  As Will points out, in the smooth case, good reduction is enough; I'm not sure there's an analogous notion of good reduction in the non-smooth case.

Comment: The other issue is that it is harder to give a good definition of good reduction.

Comment: Thank you for your answer! To clarify: does degrees of polynoms equal to dimensions of those cohomologies ?

Comment: If I understand correctly Wikipedia link requires the scheme to be smooth...

Comment: @AlexanderChervov You're right, though I'm not sure where they're using that assumption.  There's a version without smoothness assumptions in Theorem 1.2 of http://math.stanford.edu/~conrad/Weil2seminar/Notes/L20.pdf

Comment: Thank you for the reference, but I need time to think ... I think looking on examples like cusp curve will help me...

Comment: If you know some reference where cusp/node/other singular curve have been considered , that would be very helpful...